# Как сделать эффект разрыва таблицы?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как сгенерировать подобный эффект? Желательно рандомно, не подгружая заготовленные рисунки и чтобы между разрывом был задний фон... По возможности, чтобы это был элемент строки таблицы, чтобы было удобно встраивать, но не принципиально.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Добавил тег svg, чтобы расширить варианты возможных решений

Comment: clip-path, наверное, можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для имитации разрыва маску на основе SVG и примените тень ко всей таблице:

```css
/* For example only --> */ body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaA0w.png') -50% -50% / cover repeat, #fd7; background-blend-mode: overlay; }

table {
  /* For example only --> */ position: relative; top: 5px; left: 5px;
  height: auto; width: 320px;
  border: none; border-spacing: 1px;
  filter: 
    /* Цвет линий и обводки (дублируется для контраста) */ 
    drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 #000)
    /* Падающая тень */ 
    drop-shadow(8px 8px 8px #0006);
}
table th,
table td {
  height: 20px; width: 30px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table th {
  padding: 0 9px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #aab8d7;
}
table tr:first-of-type th {
  height: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td:last-of-type { text-align: center; }

/* "Зебра" */
table tr:nth-of-type(even) td { background-color: #c8deee; }
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td { background-color: #ddebf4; }

/* Строка с разрывом = Количество строк после разрыва + 1 */
table tr:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  --mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 321 26" width="321"><polyline points="0,5 10,14 16,7 29,16 34,7 41,15 55,6 64,16 79,7 94,17 108,7 114,16 121,7 149,16 172,7 185,18 202,6 214,17 220,7 237,19 259,7 267,16 282,7 299,19 308,7 313,16 321,5" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="square"/></svg>');
  --mask: var(--mask-image) 0 50% / contain repeat-x, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) 0 0 / 100% 100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); mask: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor; mask-composite: exclude;
  user-select: none;
}
table tr:nth-last-of-type(3) th,
table tr:nth-last-of-type(3) td {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
}

/* Диапазон скрываемых строк: 
   10 = Строка заголовка + Количество строк до разрыва + 1 
   4 = Строка с разрывом + Количество строк после разрыва + 1 */
table tr:nth-last-of-type(n+4):nth-of-type(n+10) { display: none; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Platz</th><th>Zeit</th><th>Name</th><th>Nummer</th></tr>
  <tr><th>1</th><td>5:11:45</td><td>Henker, Jan</td><td>5841</td></tr>
  <tr><th>2</th><td>5:49:12</td><td>Godel, Dieter</td><td>6476</td></tr>
  <tr><th>3</th><td>6:21:59</td><td>Hormanski, Piotr</td><td>5796</td></tr>
  <tr><th>4</th><td>7:04:32</td><td>Frohlich, Andy</td><td>6031</td></tr>
  <tr><th>5</th><td>7:19:04</td><td>Kruger, Christoph</td><td>5120</td></tr>
  <tr><th>6</th><td>7:41:53</td><td>Prohl, Melanie</td><td>5009</td></tr>
  <tr><th>7</th><td>7:41:56</td><td>Prohl, Christian</td><td>5010</td></tr>
  <tr><th>8</th><td>7:42:07</td><td>Humy-Zimmer, Cindy</td><td>5333</td></tr>
  <tr><th>9</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>10</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>11</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>12</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>13</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>14</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>15</th><td>8:37:27</td><td>Kretzschmar, Stefan</td><td>5681</td></tr>
  <tr><th>16</th><td>8:38:32</td><td>Purath, Andreas</td><td>6300</td></tr>
  <tr><th contenteditable>17</th><td contenteditable>8:41:09</td><td contenteditable>Cramer, Doreen</td><td contenteditable>5033</td></tr>
</table>
```

Ячейки последней строки - редактируемые. Попробуйте изменить в них текст, чтобы проверить адаптивность.

---

Если же разметка приходит уже готовая (т.е. со строкой разрыва, которую "генерит" PHP, когда нет данных), и никакие строки скрывать не требуется, то всё ещё проще - нужно добавить этой строке разрыва какой-либо класс и стилизовать по классу, а не по индексу.

```css
/* For example only --> */ body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaA0w.png') -50% -50% / cover repeat, #fd7; background-blend-mode: overlay; }

table {
  /* For example only --> */ position: relative; top: 5px; left: 5px;
  height: auto; width: 320px;
  border: none; border-spacing: 1px;
  filter: 
    /* Цвет линий и обводки (дублируется для контраста) */ 
    drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 #000)
    /* Падающая тень */ 
    drop-shadow(8px 8px 8px #0006);
  --mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 321 26" width="321"><polyline points="0,5 10,14 16,7 29,16 34,7 41,15 55,6 64,16 79,7 94,17 108,7 114,16 121,7 149,16 172,7 185,18 202,6 214,17 220,7 237,19 259,7 267,16 282,7 299,19 308,7 313,16 321,5" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="square"/></svg>');
}
table th,
table td {
  height: 20px; width: 30px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table th {
  padding: 0 9px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #aab8d7;
}
table tr:first-of-type th {
  height: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td:last-of-type { text-align: center; }

/* "Зебра" */
table tr:nth-of-type(even) td { background-color: #c8deee; }
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td { background-color: #ddebf4; }

/* Строка с разрывом */
table tr.break {
  --mask: var(--mask-image) 0 50% / auto repeat-x, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) 0 0 / 100% 100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); mask: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor; mask-composite: exclude;
  user-select: none;
}
table tr.break th,
table tr.break td {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
}
/* Строка с обрывом */
table tr:last-of-type {
  --mask: var(--mask-image) 0 50% / auto repeat-x, var(--mask-image) 0 100% / auto repeat-x, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) 0 0% / 100% 55% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); mask: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-over; mask-composite: add;
}
table tr:last-of-type th,
table tr:last-of-type td {
  height: 35px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Platz</th><th>Zeit</th><th>Name</th><th>Nummer</th></tr>
  <tr><th>1</th><td>5:11:45</td><td>Henker, Jan</td><td>5841</td></tr>
  <tr><th>2</th><td>5:49:12</td><td>Godel, Dieter</td><td>6476</td></tr>
  <tr class="break"><th>9</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>5</th><td>7:19:04</td><td>Kruger, Christoph</td><td>5120</td></tr>
  <tr><th>6</th><td>7:41:53</td><td>Prohl, Melanie</td><td>5009</td></tr>
  <tr><th>7</th><td>7:41:56</td><td>Prohl, Christian</td><td>5010</td></tr>
  <tr><th>8</th><td>7:42:07</td><td>Humy-Zimmer, Cindy</td><td>5333</td></tr>
  <tr class="break"><th>9</th><td>TIME</td><td>NAMES</td><td>NUM</td></tr>
  <tr><th>15</th><td>8:37:27</td><td>Kretzschmar, Stefan</td><td>5681</td></tr>
  <tr><th>16</th><td>8:38:32</td><td>Purath, Andreas</td><td>6300</td></tr>
  <tr><th contenteditable>17</th><td contenteditable>8:41:09</td><td contenteditable>Cramer, Doreen</td><td contenteditable>5033</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: У меня было четыре версии реализации, которые не поленился протестить. Пришёл к тому, что к "заказчику" у меня столько вопросов, что проще не участвовать.  Что напрашивается в первую очередь? ТЗ — ХЗ.   Если это разовый случай, то можно даже без SVG обойтись. Ваше решение не очень.  Допустим несколько таблиц или одна? Генерация или статика? и... после этого начинаются вопросы о реализации. Я пришёл к тому что SVG оптимальнее, но другим методом, но и разбивка таблиц на две части решает "дизайн", как и `позишн: абсолюшн` ничуть не хуже. У нас тупо нет входных данных.)

Comment: @UModeL, красиво, спасибо! Визуально меня устраивает, реализация не очень удобна, хотя к ней можно адаптироваться... Возможно да, мало входных данных с моей стороны.

Comment: @stylok, я открыт для вопросов, задавайте, всё просто) таблиц несколько, разрывы могут быть в нескольких местах, генерация, промежуточных данных нет, разрыв, как один элемент таблицы. Было бы интересно увидеть ваше решение

Comment: @Isaev, подскажите, в чём проявляется неудобство реализации? Возможно, я смогу что-то улучшить.

Comment: @UModeL в привязке к индексам в css. И в месте разрыва можно выделить и копировать предыдущую "невидимую" строку

Comment: @UModeL промежуточных данных нет, их не надо скрывать, потому их индексы не нужны в принципе. есть данные ДО, строка разрыва и данные после. Генерируется из php

Comment: @UModeL, у нас есть <tr> cо строками 1-8, потом <tr> со строкой разрыва потом <tr> со строками 16-17, промежуточных нет

Comment: @Isaev, если такая разметка приходит уже готовая (т.е. со строкой разрыва, которую генерит PHP, когда нет данных), то всё ещё проще - просто добавить этой строке какой-либо класс и стилизовать по классу, а не по индексу.

Comment: @UModeL А не подскажите как сделать, чтобы линия разрыва не дублировалась (для другого класса)? т.е. конец таблицы, разрыв и нет продолжения... Что-то я почитал документацию используемых параметров, но так и не понял как она дублируется.

Comment: @Isaev, то есть для неоконченной таблицы? Так сказать, не для _разрыва_, а для _обрыва_?

Comment: @UModeL да, для обрыва

Comment: @Isaev, добавил стили для последней строки во втором варианте.

Comment: @UModeL https://jsfiddle.net/yfx7v6ac/2/ что-то не так... именно новый стиль не отрабатывает почему-то

Comment: @Isaev, jsfiddle.net не дружит с российскими ip, а расширение и vpn ставить нет желания. Могу глянуть на codepen.io

Comment: @UModeL https://codepen.io/EDIsaev/pen/KKJwYwX

Comment: @Isaev, кроме добавления стилей, там есть ещё изменения. Внимательно просмотрите мой код и сравните с вашим. Например, перенесите `--mask-image`

Answer (score 0):

Я вот такое решение придумал. Скрываем все строки с 6 по 9 включительно

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background-color: pink;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+7) {
  display: none;
}

tr:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+8) {
 font-size: 0;
}

tr:nth-child(8)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px );
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f00;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>План</th>
    <th>Время</th>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Номер</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10-00</td>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Вместо красного фона, можете свою картинку прилепить, с этими волнами и трещиной. Высота зависит от размера ячеек... Хотя это плохое решение с точки зрения производительности. Правильнее будет на сервере разделять вывод таблицы на 2 цикла вывода. А так, это условное скрытие...

Comment: Это интересный трик) Вывод и так будет, естественно, разделён на 2 цикла, мне как раз интересно было как можно эту трещину динамически генерировать (через svg может?)

Comment: Можна через svg, или любой другой формат... это не важно. тут только от размера таблици всё зависит, а она может разтянуться если в одной из ячеек скажем будет очень длинное имя находиться.

Comment: Динамически? Зачем? Но только через JS. проще набросать и фиксированную маску. А следовательно SVG... и как следствие наклакди. Вполне легко реализуемо. Денёк посЕдеть. и задуматься над необходимостью таких решений. Нарпимер? Первое напрашивающееся, что хотелось бы "купировать" — избыточная тень.  

Задача занятная, но мало входных данных, чтобы понять цену этого фетиша. )) Кстати, лет 30 тому назад, во времена когда это [разрыво-табличное] было модно я им иногда пользовался ... полиграфия... М. Было круто))